# "error: ‘__s_getServerMD5Sum’ is not a member of" when adding a service to an existing class

Tags: ros, ur-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**TL;DR**

Trying to add two new services to a class definition but we are getting and error saying __s_getServerMD5Sum is not a member of each of them.  Our new services are implemented exactly as all of the existing services.

**Details**

We are implementing a ur_modern_driver node from: github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver

Our classes are being added to ur_ros_wrapper.cpp.  With an unmodified installation of this node everything compiles and runs as expected.  However, we need to add additional services to the RosWrapper class to provide control of the robots free drive mode.

The two new services are called enterFreeDriveMode and exitFreeDriveMode.

As far as we can tell we have implemented our new services correctly.  In short our service implementation looks like this:

//create the service servers

```
ros::ServiceServer enterFreeDriveMode_srv_;
ros::ServiceServer exitFreeDriveMode_srv_;
```

//initialize the services

```
enterFreeDriveMode_srv_ = nh_.advertiseService("ur_driver/enterFreeDriveMode", &RosWrapper::enterFreeDriveMode, this);
exitFreeDriveMode_srv_ = nh_.advertiseService("ur_driver/exitFreeDriveMode", &RosWrapper::exitFreeDriveMode, this);
```

//service callback class methods

```
bool enterFreeDriveMode(ur_msgs::EnterFreeDriveModeRequest& req, ur_msgs::EnterFreeDriveModeResponse& resp) {
            robot_.enterFreeDriveMode(true);
            resp.success = true;
        return resp.success;
    }

bool exitFreeDriveMode(ur_msgs::ExitFreeDriveModeRequest& req, ur_msgs::ExitFreeDriveModeResponse& resp) {
            robot_.exitFreeDriveMode(true);
            resp.success = true;
        return resp.success;
    }
```

//EnterFreeDriveMode.srv and ExitFreeDriveMode.srv have the exact same definition

```
bool start
---
bool success
```

When we run catkin_make we get the following errors:

```
[ 88%] Building CXX object ur_modern_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_driver.dir/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp.o In file included from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_client.h:33:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/include/ur_modern_driver/do_output.h:23,
                 from /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/include/ur_modern_driver/ur_realtime_communication.h:23,
                 from /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/include/ur_modern_driver/ur_driver.h:24,
                 from /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp:19: /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’: >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:79:102: required from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::md5sum() [with M
= ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’ >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:60:25: required from ‘void ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::init(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&) [with MReq = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void> >; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:881:5: required from ‘ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*) [with T = RosWrapper; MReq = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = > > >ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp:232:43:   required from here /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:47:34: error: ‘__s_getServerMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>’
     return M::__s_getServerMD5Sum().c_str();
                                  ^ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>]’: >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:79:102: required from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::md5sum() [with M
= ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>]’ >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:60:47: required from ‘void ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::init(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&) [with MReq = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:881:5: required from ‘ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*) [with T = RosWrapper; MReq = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp:232:43:   required from here /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:47:34: error: ‘__s_getServerMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::DataType<M>::value() [with M = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’: >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:88:104: required from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::datatype() [with M = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’ >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:72:34: required from ‘void ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::init(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&) [with MReq = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:881:5: required from ‘ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*) [with T = RosWrapper; MReq = ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp:232:43:   required from here /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:64:37: error: ‘__s_getServiceDataType’ is not a member of ‘ur_msgs::enterFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>’
     return M::__s_getServiceDataType().c_str();
                                     ^ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’: >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:79:102: required from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::md5sum() [with M
= ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’ >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:60:25: required from ‘void ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::init(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&) [with MReq = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:881:5: required from ‘ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*) [with T = RosWrapper; MReq = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp:234:42:   required from here /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:47:34: error: ‘__s_getServerMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>’
     return M::__s_getServerMD5Sum().c_str();
                                  ^ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>]’: >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:79:102: required from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::md5sum() [with M
= ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>]’ >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:60:47: required from ‘void ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::init(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&) [with MReq = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:881:5: required from ‘ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*) [with T = RosWrapper; MReq = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp:234:42:   required from here /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:47:34: error: ‘__s_getServerMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::service_traits::DataType<M>::value() [with M = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’: >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:88:104: required from ‘const char* ros::service_traits::datatype() [with M = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>]’ >/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:72:34: required from ‘void ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::init(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&) [with MReq = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:881:5: required from ‘ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*) [with T = RosWrapper; MReq = ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>; MRes = >ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeResponse_<std::allocator<void>>; std::__cxx11::string = >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ /home/evilbot/catkin_ws/src/ur_modern_driver/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp:234:42:   required from here /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/service_traits.h:64:37: error: ‘__s_getServiceDataType’ is not a member of ‘ur_msgs::exitFreeDriveModeRequest_<std::allocator<void>>’
     return M::__s_getServiceDataType().c_str();
                                     ^ ur_modern_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_driver.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'ur_modern_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_driver.dir/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp.o' failed make[2]: *** [ur_modern_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_driver.dir/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1417: recipe for target 'ur_modern_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_driver.dir/all' failed make[1]: *** [ur_modern_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_driver.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2 Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

**Environment**

- ROS Kinetic Kame
- Ubuntu 16.04.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274914/%22error:-%E2%80%98__s_getservermd5sum%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of%22-when-adding-a-service-to-an-existing-class/) by [3mul0r](https://answers.ros.org/users/32491/3mul0r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
You've lef out the most important bit of info: the `ur_msgs/EnterFreeDriveMode` and `ur_msgs/ExitFreeDriveMode` service definitions. Those are not standard services, so you need to include those.

I'm guessing, but depending no your svc defs, it should be `resp.success.data = true;`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:\

> Our new services are implemented exactly as all of the existing services.

Also: did you create new service defs?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
FInally: please edit your original question and copy-paste the compiler error message again. Then please select it and press the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it). Don't use 'block comments' for code/error msgs/etc.

**Comment by [3mul0r](https://answers.ros.org/users/32491/3mul0r/) on 2017-11-04**:
Updated.  Sorry I should have got those the first time.
I also noted that these classes are being added to ur_ros_wrapper.cpp if you want to see the original on GH.  All of the existing services use `resp.success = true;`.  I'll give that a shot later today though.  Thx!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:\

> I also noted that these classes are being added to ur_ros_wrapper.cpp

not sure what this means.

To add a service server:

1. write a new srv spec
2. `#include` the header(s) in the file you're going to add the srv to
3. add `ros::ServiceServer`s
4. add callbacks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
Suggestion: if all you're doing is triggering something, I would not create custom services, but use [std_srvs/Trigger](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_srvs/html/srv/Trigger.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We experienced this error when adding our new services to an existing class that was fully functional.  We also verified that we received the same error on a second system.  We added our code to the second system from scratch to ensure we wouldn't copy over some unseen coding error.  This issue continued to persist through many hours of debugging.

In the end we attempted to recreate this issue on a fresh install of Ubuntu and ros kinetic.  Fortunately for us the fresh environment resolved the issue.  Same code, fresh install, no issues.  We have since done a fresh install on all our dev systems and are up and running with our additional services.  Now that we have cleaned our dev systems this issue can no longer be recreated.

---

Originally posted by [3mul0r](https://answers.ros.org/users/32491/3mul0r/) with karma: 16 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-22**:
I'm happy that you got things to work for you, but this should not have been needed.

Did you at any point `rm -rf` your `catkin_ws/devel` and `catkin_ws/build` directories? There is some heavy caching / creation of references / symlinks there which could have interfered.